# How to access gtkmm object from other function?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I want to change the properties of a gtk window after it has been loaded, for which I will need to access the object from another function than main(). For this example changeWidget() is called from main(), but I want to link it to a button later. How would I have to make "buttons" accessible from changeWidget?

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "buttons.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

Buttons buttons;

void changeWidget()
{
    buttons.set_title("title");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
   Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  changeWidget();

  return app->run(buttons);
}
```

Comment: Generally in GTK everything should be handled by a callback.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by oldtechaa, the standard way of doing this is to use a callback. 
Here's an example:

(I'm assuming you want to change the window title because you specifically mention the set_title function)

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

void changeWidget(Gtk::Window& window)
{
  window.set_title("changeWidget Title");
}

struct my_window : Gtk::Window
{
  my_window() : my_button("button")
  {
    set_default_size(400,200);
    set_title("Original Title");
    add(my_button);

    my_button.signal_clicked().
      connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &my_window::handle_my_button_click));

    show_all();
  }

private:
  void handle_my_button_click()
  {
    // set_title("Button Changed Title"); // typically done directly, here
    changeWidget(*this);  // but you could call another function like this
  }

  Gtk::Button my_button;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);

  my_window window;

  return app->run(window);
}
```

Hope this helps.